# Communication Exception while calling .asmx service from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, crossdomain.xml

I have a .asmx web service which is hosted on IIS. I took the service reference and i am calling this web service from my silverlight application. But i am getting a communication exception as follows.

> An error occurred while trying to make
>   a request to URI
>   'http://test.bookmyshow.com/services/wsDebtorTrans.asmx'.
>   This could be due to attempting to
>   access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy
>   in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may
>   need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain
>   policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
>   This error may also be caused by using
>   internal types in the web service
>   proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.
>   Please see the inner exception for
>   more details.

I have added the required policy files (clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml) to my web service. Following is the content of my clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml

[crossdomain.xml](http://test.bookmyshow.com/services/crossdomain.xml) and [clientaccesspolicy](http://test.bookmyshow.com/services/clientaccesspolicy.xml)

I tried to access the above two files from my browser and the xml files are displayed properly in my browser. I have used basicHttpBinding. I have seen lot of tutorials online and tried them but still I am facing the same problem. Am I missing anything here? Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you only need a `CrossDomain.xml` file OR a `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` file.  You don't need both.  Also, where did you put those files?  Did you put it in the `Services` folder, or did you put it in the root of the server?  For example, http://test.bookmyshow.com/ClientAccessPolicy.xml instead of http://test.bookmyshow.com/Services/ClientAccessPolicy.xml .  The file should be put in the Root of your application and not the `Services` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have placed the file inside the services folder. Is this the right location ?. Just out of curiosity, is there any harm if i have included both crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml files in my web service

Comment: Updated my answer.  The file should be in the root of your application and not the Services folder.  There's not technically any harm with having both - Silverlight will just check for one before the other.  However that means you have to keep both files up to date, and that creates a possible security hole (if your particular application cares about that).